# MOOC about GARCH model

Tags: time-series, references, garch

I have a fundamental math PhD background, but very little knowledge (only undergraduate) about statistics.

Even by reading lots of online documents about [GARCH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_conditional_heteroskedasticity#GARCH), I find it hard to find the global philosophy.

I'd like to find a MOOC about GARCH, and more generally time series. What are your recommendations?

Comment: Why did some people vote for this as being too broad? I think it is a very well defined question: "*Is there a MOOC that covers GARCH models? And if not is there a MOOC on time-series?*" Which part is the "broad part"?

Comment: Just a warning: I think it's unlikely you will find a MOOC on GARCH's: this a somewhat advanced time series method. MOOC's tend to be more '101' classes. Looking for a general time series MOOC is likely to give you more traction.

Comment: @CliffAB Yes that's what I am looking for : an online course about advanced time series methods.